# How to parse this xml in required format if the xml has no child parent structure

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml given below.How should i parse this so that i can store in the array to display it in the structure like the below.

need to dispaly spec group first and then title and value for each group..

For example

```
group title          Specidentifier  Specvalue 

Audi specifications   Power           5w x 2
                      Maximum SPL     –90 dB
                      ..........      ......

General Specifications Battery type   11.1 V, 2500 mAh Lithium
                       Power Max      54 M Maximum
```

Below is the xml. I have tried by converting this into array.But it becomes difficult for me as this tags(product_spec_identifier1) are repeating under each group.

```
<product_published_start>31-07-2013</product_published_start>
<product_published_end>31-07-2013</product_published_end>
<product_spec_group1>Audio Specifications</product_spec_group1>
<product_spec_identifier1>Power</product_spec_identifier1>
<product_spec_value1>65W x 2</product_spec_value1>
<product_spec_value1_language>en</product_spec_value1_language>
<product_spec_identifier2>Maximum SPL</product_spec_identifier2>
<product_spec_value2>–90 dB</product_spec_value2>
<product_spec_value2_language>en</product_spec_value2_language>
<product_spec_identifier3>Slew rate</product_spec_identifier3>
<product_spec_value3>40V/μsec</product_spec_value3>
<product_spec_value3_language>en</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_identifier4>Sensitivity/impendance</product_spec_identifier4>
<product_spec_value4>250mV/46k ohms</product_spec_value4>
<product_spec_value4_language>en</product_spec_value4_language>
<product_spec_identifier5>Dynamic Range adjustment</product_spec_identifier5>
<product_spec_value5>90dB</product_spec_value5>
<product_spec_value5_language>en</product_spec_value5_language>
<product_spec_identifier6>Type</product_spec_identifier6>
<product_spec_value6>Multimedia Speakers</product_spec_value6>
<product_spec_value6_language>en</product_spec_value6_language>
<product_spec_identifier7>Frequency Response</product_spec_identifier7>
<product_spec_value7>60 Hz – 20 kHz</product_spec_value7>
<product_spec_value7_language>en</product_spec_value7_language>
<product_spec_identifier8>Signal-to-Noise Ratio</product_spec_identifier8>
<product_spec_value8>dB</product_spec_value8>
<product_spec_value8_language>en</product_spec_value8_language>
<product_spec_group2>General Specifications</product_spec_group2>
<product_spec_identifier1>Battery type</product_spec_identifier1>
<product_spec_value1>11.1 V, 2500 mAh Lithium</product_spec_value1>
<product_spec_value1_language>en</product_spec_value1_language>
<product_spec_identifier2>Power Max</product_spec_identifier2>
<product_spec_value2>54 M Maximum</product_spec_value2>
<product_spec_value2_language>en</product_spec_value2_language>
<product_spec_identifier3>Power requirement</product_spec_identifier3>
<product_spec_value3>100 – 240V AC, 50/60Hz</product_spec_value3>
<product_spec_value3_language>en</product_spec_value3_language>
<product_spec_identifier4>Dimensions (H x W x D)</product_spec_identifier4>
<product_spec_value4>300 mm X 164 mm x 275 mm</product_spec_value4>
<product_spec_value4_language>en</product_spec_value4_language>
<product_spec_identifier5>Weight</product_spec_identifier5>
<product_spec_value5>2,7 Kg</product_spec_value5>
<product_spec_value5_language>en</product_spec_value5_language>
<product_spec_identifier6>Dimensions: Subwoofer (H x W x D – Metric/English)</product_spec_identifier6>
<product_spec_value6>345 mm x 222 mm x 325 mm</product_spec_value6>
<product_spec_value6_language>en</product_spec_value6_language>
<product_spec_identifier7>Colour</product_spec_identifier7>
<product_spec_value7>Black</product_spec_value7>
<product_spec_value7_language>en</product_spec_value7_language>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an xslt to do this check w3 schools for xslt examples